# All pdf images are rotated. png images are the correct orientation

Tags: graphics, pdftex, rotating

I am working on a large collaborative document on overleaf, where all images look fine. When I clone a local copy to work on, all the pdf plots are rotated 90°, while all the .png plots are the correct orientation. Some pdfs are placed in landscape on purpose, so I am using `\usepackage{rotating}`. Using the TexpadTex typesetter.

A sample of how I'm typically using images:

```
\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{GammaHadron/13def_Subtracted.pdf}
\caption{$\Delta\phi$ projections in p+Pb collisions after correlated decay photons are scaled by 1-purity and subtracted from our signal shower shape region. The vertical bars represent the statistical uncertainty, and the grey boxes represent the statistical uncertainty.}
\label{Correlated_Subtracted}
\end{figure}
```

**Edit:** Sorry for the delay. I posted a minimum working example. The example is so simple, perhaps it's a problem with my typesetter?

**Edit 2:** After some digging, I've found the images generated by ROOT data analysis framework are rotated, while images generated by python/jupyter notebook are the correct orientation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{GammaHadron/13def_Eta_Inclusive.png}
\caption{caption}
\label{fig:pPbinclusivephotonETA}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\center
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{GammaHadron/13def_Inclusive_Phi.pdf}
\caption{caption.}
\label{fig:pPbinclusivephotonPhi}    
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The output is: [image]

Comment: please provide a full MWE.

Comment: with test images from `graphicx` package (`example-image`) is not possible to reproduce your problem. please provide complete small document begininning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `end{document}` which reproduce your problem. does your image in pdf and pgf format has the same orientation?

Comment: @Zarko, Thanks. I posted an MWE. Yes, when viewed as separate files, as well as on overleaf they both appear correct.

Comment: @FernandoTorales-Acosta, this mwe gives expected result, both my test images has the same orientation. this means that your png and pdf images are hasnt the same orientation. please show us result of your mwe.

Comment: @Zarko Update with image.

Comment: sorry, but this image are not generated by provided  document example. if all your `late` code is written on the same way as in provided example, means that your png and pdf version of those image are different. how they are generated?

Comment: @Zarko I'm using TexPad on MacOs; the TexPadTex typesetter. The images are in the correct orientation before typesetting (in fact, TexPad offers a preview where the pdf's are in the correct orientation). Not sure if this answers your follow up.